# Filter result when use GET

Tags: json, bash

I like to get only one parameter when execute this command:

```
curl -X GET http://${HUE}/api/${API}/lights/1
```

I need only to show **true**/**false** that see in this parameter **{"state":{"on":**

How can modify the GET to show only this instead the actual result?

```
{"state":{"on":true,"bri":90,"alert":"select","mode":"homeautomation","reachable":true},"swupdate":{"state":"noupdates","lastinstall":"2019-01-04T22:37:21"},"type":"Dimmable light","name":"Bombeta menjador 1","modelid":"LWB010","manufacturername":"Philips","productname":"Hue white lamp",...
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a valid json and you have access to `jq` utility, you can just:

```
curl .... | jq --compact-output '.state.on'
```

which will output `true` or `false` depending on the value.

Comment: like to use as similar command not's possible? curl -X GET -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"state": "on"}' http://${HUE}/api/${API}/lights/1